# calling data-onsuccess method for Google sign-in

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to integrate [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) into my web app.

My page has the Google button:

```
ModalDialogue.cshtml:

<a class="google g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">Sign up with Google+</a>
```

I'm trying to trigger that method in my js:

```
ModalDialogue.js:

      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
      }
```

I know that

a] the JavaScript is in the scope of the page, since my other functions - for opening and closing the dialogue - DO work.

b] the button is communicating with Google, since clicking on it DOES open the 'sign-in with Google' dialogue - and then once done - changes the button to 'Sign In' afterward.

How do I trigger the onSignIn method? Or at least how do I determine whether onsuccess is being triggered?

Comment: Did you pass the parameter in `data-onsuccess` function for `onSignIn` function within the `a` tag?

Comment: Seems like it should just happen automatically.  Perhaps include additional details about how you implemented the integration and what is actually happening when you try to sign in.

Comment: What does this have to do with Chrome Extensions?

Comment: I'm implementing this:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
I've got a client ID, but I'm simply trying to figure out how data-onsuccess is triggered.

Comment: This, at least, should work:
`  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log("Foo");
  }`

Comment: any solution to that problem?

Comment: I am having exact same problem.  onSuccess function is global scope.  Login appears to go fine, but the onSuccess is never called and there is no error message.

Comment: @AgilePro were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Oh. My bad. I hadn't noticed I had the method wrapped in a closure. Needs to be global.

Answer (score 4):

For people who come to this page in the future, I had to move the function definition above the button tag. Seems like it shouldn't matter, as data-onsuccess is simply a string. It didn't throw any error messages, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

for for info[for info](http://dsprock.com/?p=178)

Comment: Could you give an explainer as to what you've done here? That would be extra helpful

Answer (score 0):

Define the function onSignIn in script tag, which will make it available globally.

```
<script>
          function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            console.log("I am clicked");
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
            console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
            console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
          }
</script>
```

To check if your function is available globally or not, call window.onSignIn() or onSignIn() from console. You should be able to call onSignIn if it is global.

The script tag can be put at the bottom inside body tag (tested with React js),

```
<body>
....
<script>
...
</script></body>
```

alternatively it can be put inside head with async or defer attribute.

This will do its magic then,

```
<div className="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

enable third party cookie in your browser